# Common interface without dependency to specific logic

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Lets assume that I have 3 projects

- Common
- Web
- Core

`Web` and `Core` have reference to `Common`. Idea is that `Common` project contains common interfaces for `Web` and `Core`.

Let assume that in both projects I have some mapping and I want to have common interface for this. For example on `Web` project I want use AutoMapper, and on `Core` project I want to use something else.

For AutoMapper I need interface.

```
    using AutoMapper;
    namespace Common.Mapper
    {
        public interface IMapperConfiguration
        {
            IMapper GetMapper();
        }
    }
```

This is working in `Web` project, but I cannot move this interface to `Common` project since this interface has dependency to AutoMapper (IMapper is from AutoMapper).

How to create common interface for this?
Is there some design pattern that I can use?

Mapper is just an example. I would like to know how to resolve problems like this.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sounds like `IMapperConfiguration` isn't common - what's the problem?

Comment: Mapping is common functionality, I want have common interface for common functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your interface common. It cannot return an implementation of IMapper if you are not making AutoMapper common to both projects. Forgive me as I don't use automapper but you would be looking at wrapping it in a class implementing your own IMapper interface something like:

```
namespace Common.Mapper
{
    public interface IMapper
    {
        void Map(...args...);
    }
}

namespace Web.Mapper
{
    public class Mapper : Common.Mapper.IMapper
    {
        public void Map(...args...)
        {
            AutoMapper.Map(...args...);
        }
    }
}

namespace Core.Mapper
{
    public class Mapper : Common.Mapper.IMapper
    {
        public void Map(...args...)
        {
            SomeOtherMapper.Map(...args...);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And it's worth mentioning that this is an example of [adapter](http://www.dofactory.com/net/adapter-design-pattern) design pattern.

Comment: So based on this link I understand (and correct me if I am wrong) that from this example 1- Common.Mapper.IMapper is Target. 2- Core.Mapper & Web.Mapper are Adapters. 3- AutoMapper & SomeOtherMapper are Adaptee. Am I right?

Comment: In other words: I adapt 'AutoMaper' and 'SomeOtherMapper' to 'Common.Mapper.IMapper' and for this I am using adapters 'Web.Mapper' and 'Core.Mapper'.

Comment: Yes your web and core mappers are adapters / wrappers